# What is a twigil in Perl6?

Tags: perl, terminology, raku

I'm reading this fantastic [introduction to Perl6](https://github.com/rakudo/star/raw/master/docs/2015-spw-perl6-course.pdf) and came across a rather interesting term:

> Note the `!` ***twigil*** means “this is private to the class”.
>
> ```
> class ScoreKeeper {
>   has %!player-points;
> }
> ```

I know what [sigils are](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-%24array%5b1%5d-and-%40array%5b1%5d%3f) in Perl5. But what's a *twigil*?

Is it just a fancy way to say that there are two sigils prepending the attribute/variable name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The design documents [S02](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Twigils) and [S99](https://design.perl6.org/S99.html#twigil) both talk about *twigils*. (Emphasis mine).

> Ordinary sigils indicate normally scoped variables, either lexical or
>   package scoped. **Oddly scoped variables include a secondary sigil (a
>   twigil)** that indicates what kind of strange scoping the variable is
>   subject to: [...]

So it is a **secondary sigil** or rather a **second** sigil. Declaring `$*foo` will not declare `$foo`.

```
my $*foo = 1;
say $foo;
```

This will yield *Variable '$foo' is not declared at...*.

Comment: I'd like to add that _lizmat_ on irc.perl.org helped me understand the concept.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to be related to variable scoping:

> Twigils influence the scoping of a variable...
>
> ```
> Twigil   Scope
> ------   ----------------------------------------------
> none     Based only on declarator
> *        Dynamic
> !        Attribute (class member)
> ?        Compile-time variable
> .        Method (not really a variable)
> <        Index into match object (not really a variable)
> ^        Self-declared formal positional parameter
> :        Self-declared formal named parameter
> =        Pod variables
> ~        The sublanguage seen by the parser at this lexical spot
> ```

http://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Twigils

Answer (score 9):

From [the documentation on twigils](http://docs.raku.org/language/variables#The_!_Twigil):

> Attributes are variables that exist per instance of a class. They may be directly accessed from within the class via !:

```
class Point {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;

    method Str() {
        "($!x, $!y)"
    }
}
```

> Note how the attributes are declared as `$.x` and `$.y` but are still accessed via `$!x` and `$!y`. This is because in Perl 6 all attributes are private and can be directly accessed within the class by using `$!attribute-name`. Perl 6 may automatically generate accessor methods for you though. For more details on objects, classes and their attributes see [object orientation](http://docs.raku.org/language/objects).

Public attributes have the `.` twigil, private ones the `!` twigil.

```
class YourClass {
    has $!private;
    has @.public;

    # and with write accessor
    has $.stuff is rw;

    method do_something {
        if self.can('bark') {
            say "Something doggy";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, there's a shedload of them in the documentation!